# What is the joint density function of U and V in given problem below?

Tags: random-variables, density-function

Let X and Y be two independent random variables. Let us define two functions as follows:
$$U:=\lambda_1 X+ \lambda_2Y$$
$$V:=\lambda_3\sqrt{XY}$$
What is the joint density function of U and V i.e., $f_{UV}(u,v)$ ?

Some more descriptions:

X and Y are iid exponential random variables with unity mean. The joint density function of X and Y is defined as below $$f_{XY}(x,y)=e^{-(x+y)} ;x \geq 0, y \geq 0$$

Using density transformation, we can have the joint density function of U and V i.e., $f_{UV}(u,v)$ as follows-$$f_{UV}(u,v)=\sum_{i}f_{XY}(x_i,y_i)|J_{g_i}(x_i,y_i)|^{-1} \label{eqn_7}$$.

where the solution pair $(x_i,y_i)$ is the i'th solution of above U and V equations and $J_g(x_i,y_i)$ denotes the Jacobian of the function $g(x,y)$.

Am I in write track? If one can solve the rest, I can cross-check my derivation with them.

Comment: Please show your effort.

Comment: @geetha290krm can you please tell me , what kind of effort you are talking about?

Comment: @AsifIkbalMondalee19s014 What you have tried, what definition do you know about the joint density function, and what issues you're facing to use the definition of tackle the problem. Please update the question with those elements.